# C: Freeing a pointer from another function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Say, I have 2 functions like these-

```
char* f2(void){
    char* str = malloc(100);
    strcpy(str, "string1");
    return str;
}

char* f1(void){
    char* reply = malloc(150);
    strcpy(reply, "string = ");
    strcat(reply, f2());
    return reply;
}
```

Which I call from main like so-

```
printf("reply = %s", f1());
```

My question:
Is it sufficient for me to free(reply) alone or do I have to free(str) explicitly in f1()?

Comment: you allocate twice, you have to `free()` twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to free the return value of `f1()`, too. Change

```
strcat(reply, f2());
```

to:

```
char *str = f2();
strcat(reply, str);
free(str);
```

Comment: Impressive. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

whatever you allocate manually (ex: malloc, calloc, etc), you have to free manually..

Answer (score 2):

In function `f1` you have to free the returned pointer of function `f2` Otherwise there will be a memory leak

```
char* f1(void){
    char* reply = malloc(150);
    char *str = f2();

    strcpy(reply, "string = ");
    strcat(reply, str);
    free( str );

    return reply;
}
```

Also in main you have to free the pointer returned by function `f1`

```
char *reply = f1();

printf("reply = %s", reply );

free( reply );
```